# Need to get the params from route in Angular 7 Router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a problem with my params in my router.

```
{
  path: 'profile',
  component: ProfileComponent,
  canActivate:[AuthGuard],
  children: [
    {
      path: 'section/:id/:idarticle',
      component: WriteArticleComponent,
    },
  ]
}
```

It is working okay. My page is opening as it should.

I formed link to this component in this case

```
<a [routerLink]="['/profile/section', item.idSection, item.id]">
```

And in browser url I have this

```
http://localhost:59955/profile/section/7002/5005
```

But in this page I need to get the params from route. And I can get only the first

```
this.idSection = this.router.snapshot.params.id;
this.idArticle = this.router.params['id-article'];
```

Second will always undefined

I tried to form my url by this way

```
<a [routerLink]="['/profile/section/']" [queryParams]="{id: 
item.idSection, article: item.id}">
```

And I have this in browser

```
http://localhost:59955/profile/section?id=7002?idarticle=5005
```

And this router is not working. Link will no redirect there. If I try to force there in browser. Its redirected me to

```
http://localhost:59955/profile/section
```

How can I organize my work with router and link, where I can easy get all the params.

Comment: the problem with the old code this.router.params['id-article'] is that this.router.params is returning an observable which you have to subscribe and only from that you can get the param details

Comment: For example :
this.router.params.subscribe(async param=>{
   data=param.get('idarticle');
})

Comment: other than that you can take it by snapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get params with first approch something like

```
this.router.params.subscribe(data=>{
  this.idArticle=data['idarticle'];
  this.idSection =data['id'];
});
```

In case of second approch you will need to change `path: 'section/:id/:idarticle',` to `path: 'section',` and then get queryparams like

```
this.router.queryParams.subscribe(data=>{
  this.idArticle=data['idarticle'];
  this.idSection =data['id'];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You retrieve the first parameter via snapshot

```
this.idSection = this.router.snapshot.params.id;
```

and the second directly via parameters

```
this.idArticle = this.router.params['id-article'];
```

The latter does not return the given parameter, but an *Observable* containing said parameter. On the other hand when calling `router.snapshot` a snapshot is created that contains the values of the parameters at that point of time.

Thus you can either use the snapshot as well (if you know that your params will not change) or you should use the observable for both parameters and react to changes that might occur.